# Custom Lottie animation not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, lottie

React Native Version: react-native: 0.59.8

Lottie Version: "lottie-react-native": "^3.3.2"

Animation is working using this animation: https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/Hhw0wgYmETDTkxW/data.json

But not this one (my custom one): https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_NJ8xgn.json

React Native Code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
    import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.animation.play();
        // Or set a specific startFrame and endFrame with:
        // this.animation.play(30, 120);
      }

      resetAnimation = () => {
        this.animation.reset();
        this.animation.play();
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.animationContainer}>
            <LottieView
              ref={animation => {
                this.animation = animation;
              }}
              style={{
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                backgroundColor: '#eee',
              }}
              source={require('./assets/gradientBall.json')}
              // OR find more Lottie files @ https://lottiefiles.com/featured
              // Just click the one you like, place that file in the 'assets' folder to the left, and replace the above 'require' statement
            />
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Button title="Restart Animation" onPress={this.resetAnimation} />
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      animationContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
      },
      buttonContainer: {
        paddingTop: 20,
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your lottie version

## Installing (React Native == 0.59.x)

### Install lottie-react-native (3.0.2) and lottie-ios (3.0.3):

```
yarn add lottie-react-native@3.0.2
yarn add lottie-ios@3.0.3
```

or

```
npm i --save lottie-react-native@3.0.2
npm i --save lottie-ios@3.0.3
```

### Use react-native link to add the library to your project:

```
react-native link lottie-ios
react-native link lottie-react-native
```

In case of Expo as of now it works with version 2 of lottie
[image: Expo-lottie]

Comment: That didn't work. I should mention I'm using Expo as well.

Comment: I have modified my answer please check it.  Use lottie-react-native version 2 instead of version 3

Comment: I have te same problem.. it gives me the error: Unable to resolve "lottie-react-native"

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade to React Native 0.60+

We were running into the *exact* same thing as you on React Native 0.59.10. I tried to "config" our way around it but, alas, no joy.

Instead, we went through the painstaking process of updating from 0.59.10 to 0.60.6 just to get this working and after a few days of upgrade hell, Lottie works perfectly now without any monkeying around.

You're gonna have to do it eventually, so that would be my recommendation. Two birds, one arduous stone.